# How to get DQL result from the template with symfony 1.4?

Tags: php, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I'm working with symfony 1.4 and Doctrine. I'm writing an app about some pubs/bars, and I've got 4 tables:

- products
- orders
- product_order
- pubs.

I want to get the times all products have been ordered in the first pub (i.e. pubs.id = 1). This is what I've got, but I can only get the sum of the first product (products.id = 1) and I need the sum of all of them, in this case there are two different products in my db.

ProductOrderTable:

```
public function ordersGetCount(){

    $q = Doctrine_Query::create()

      ->from('ProductOrder l')
      ->innerJoin('l.Order p ON l.id_order = p.id')
      ->select('SUM(l.amount) as units')
      ->andWhere('p.id_pub = 1')
      ->groupBy('l.id_product')
      ->orderBy('p.id');
   return $q->execute();
}
```

Here my action class:

```
$this->resultCount= Doctrine_Core::getTable('productorder')->ordersGetCount();
```

And here my template:

```
 for($i=0; $i<2; $i++){

          echo "<tr>";

          echo  "<td>".$resultCount[0]->getUnits()[$i]."</td>";//   
          echo  "<td>1</td>";
          echo  "<td>1</td>";
          echo "</tr>";


      }
```

Please need help :)

Comment: sorry but...can you explain a little better your kind of problem?

Comment: i want to get the sum(l.amount) of each product. the query is working i think, but i dont't know how to go through "$resultCount->getUnits()"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's nothing wrong with your query, but you should have a look at how you display your results.

```
echo  "<td>".$resultCount[0]->getUnits()[$i]."</td>";
```

Firstly, you're always referring to the first element in the `$resultCount` array. Secondly, I'm not sure if you can use a getter for a virtual column (you're not using a column which is mapped to your model.

So I would go with something like this:

1. In the `ordersGetCount` I would use

   ```
   return $q->fetchArray();
   ```

   This will return an array of arrays, not an array of objects, and will allow you to access the virtual column `units`.
2. To display the results:

   ```
   <?php foreach ($resultCount as $row): ?>
       <tr>
           <td>
               <?php echo $row['units']; ?>
           </td>   
           <td>1</td>
           <td>1</td>
       </tr>
   <?php endforeach ?>
   ```

EDIT:

This is quite strange ;) Can you try to build the query this way: (in theory it should be the same):

```
 $q = $this->createQuery('l')
     ->select('l.id_product, sum(l.amount) as units')
     ->innerJoin('l.Order')
     ->where('p.id_pub = 1')
     ->groupBy('l.id_product')
     ->orderBy('p.id');
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michal, I found a function to try the SQL and its not the problem it works good, i tried your suggestion but it only prints one record it must print 2, if i try to access manually to the second record (resultCount[1]['units']) it says Undeffined offset 1.
More suggestions please im getting mad :(

Comment: Did you run the query against the database and made absolutely sure that it should return two rows? That you have two different products associated with `id_pub = 1`?

Comment: 100% sure, phpmyadmin returns 2 rows.

Comment: Hold on, Hold on, i think its a problem in my DB, i try to fix it, BRB

Comment: No, its perfect, im starting to see things where there arent.  :(

Comment: Stay calm, breathe deeply - we'll find the cause eventually ;) Can you show us the SQL that is produced by Doctrine?

Comment: SELECT sum(amount) as units from product_order inner Join order on order.id=product_order.id_order where order.id_pub=1 group by id_product order by order.id

Comment: Hm... Strange. I have added a bit modified version of the query builder. Can yuo check if it changes anything (in theory it shouldn't, but who knows...). Can you also post what this statement produces (inside the `ordersGetCount()` function: `var_dump($q->getSqlQuery())`;

Comment: it works!! lots of thanks dude, this doctrine is broken hehehehe. Cyaa

Answer (score 0):

You must try remove

```
->groupBy('l.id_product')
```

it reduces you results to one product.